# Posing a modeled hand

Tags: rigging, armature

I modeled a hand and added an armature, but when I tried to pose the hand, the armature moved faster than the mesh. In fact it moved outside the mesh. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple armature modifiers? If this is not the issue, could you upload a .blend or screenshot showing the setup and errant behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you used 'Automatic weights'. A reason could be that the piece of the hand that you want to control with this bone, this same piece is also controlled by another bone. This results in a mix of both bones. You have to find out which other unwanted bone is also controlling that piece of hand and edit its weights. But I'm not sure whether this is what you mean, I could be wrong :)